# How can I bind a key to an automatic timestamp in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, timestamp, javadoc

Eclipse is very handy for generating javadocs for me.  I have it set up to generate a class javadoc in the following format simply by pressing Ctrl-Shift-J:

```
/**
 *****************************************************************************
 * Class name - Desc
 *
 * @author Scott Johnson
 * @version 1 <timestamp>
 *****************************************************************************
 */
```

I'd like to be able to generate a new @version tag, though, with a similar keypress.  Is there any way I can bind a key combination (such as Ctrl-Alt-Shift-T or V) to automatically place a new timestamp in the comment?

Ideally, I'd like to have something that would add a new version to the class javadoc - so if I had something like:

```
 /**
 *****************************************************************************
 * MyClass - A simple example
 *
 * @author Scott Johnson
 * @version 1 1:36:04 PM Feb 16, 2010
 *****************************************************************************
 */
```

And I pressed Ctrl-Alt-Shift-T (or whatever) over the class name, it would add the following line:

```
 * @version 2 2:28:04 PM Nov 16, 2010
```

underneath

```
 * @version 1 1:36:04 PM Feb 16, 2010
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to create a Template  (Java -> Editor -> Templates if you are using java).

Name the new template "@version" and in the pattern field write:

```
${cursor} ${time} ${date}
```

This will insert the current date and type and place your mouse cursor where in your current example the version number would go.

Now when you are in the java perspective and you write @version pressing command spacebar should execute your template.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the responsibility of your source control management software to keep track of versions and corresponding dates.

If you are not familiar with the concept of checking in and out of a source repository, now would be a good time to do so.  You might find the introduction at http://hginit.com/ interesting.

Comment: This is not what I was asking.  I am familiar with how to do it another way, namely source control.  I am asking if there is a way to bind a timestamp to a key in Eclipse.

Comment: Could you please explain how to accomplish that?